# Observer Design Pattern: Few Questions

Tags: multithreading, observer-pattern

I am going through the Observer Design Pattern and have a few questions on which I don't have a definitive answer, so would appreciate any thoughts/ideas around them. This is specifically around asynchronous observer callbacks in multi-threaded scenarios:

1. What is the best way to design this, when its known that the observer can receive multiple event notifications from the subject in very short time intervals. So, its very much possible to get multiple notifications even when a single callback was not complete. How to handle this? How to use locking effectively?
2. How to handle unsubscribe requests when the callback is still executing? How to avoid deadlocks in this scenario?

I think we can start discussing this first and am sure we will have more questions as the answers pour in. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You did not mention how do you wish the observer to handle notifications- concurrently, one by one? Is the handling thread-safe?

Comment: The preferred way of handling notifications is concurrently. And the handling is not thread-safe.

Comment: And how big are the bursts? a few per second/hundreds per second?

Comment: There would be continous stream. May be around 50-60 per second.

Comment: Then it seems you need to check out the producer-consumer pattern, not the observer pattern. BTW, what language?

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy, will go through that too. Its for C++.

Answer (score 1):

**Answers:**

1. In order to handle multiple notifications while the first one completes, you can consider using a semaphore and a callback queue to ensure that only one callback is serviced and any point of time. Once complete, based on FIFO, chuck that out and move on to the next callback in the queue.
2. If you are using a waiting queue and a semaphore then handling unsubscribe requests also becomes easy wherein you can loop through all callbacks in the queue waiting to be serviced and `splice` out (in javascript terms) the callback that has been unsubscribed.

Comment: A Semaphore, you mean binary semaphore i.e. Mutex?

Comment: Depends on your scenario. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) definition says "Semaphore is as a record of how many units of a particular resource are available". If in your case there is a single servicing end-point then ofcourse a Mutex, otherwise a semaphore.